# Examples of prime ideals for Lie algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, lie-algebras, classical-mechanics, quantum-mechanics

I am looking for examples of prime ideals for Lie algebras. In particular, I am interested in examples involving the Lie algebra given by the commutator of endomorphisms of a complex vector space and the Lie algebra of functions on the [phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) $\mathbb{R}^{2n}=(x^1,\ldots,x^n,p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ given by
$$
[f,g]=\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial g}{\partial p_i}-
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_i},
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are real or complex-valued functions on the phase space.

My interest has originated in physics, where the time derivative of a physical "observable" $X$ can generally be written (except for multiplicative constants) as
$$
\frac{d X}{d t} = [H,X], 
$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian operator in quantum mechanics or the Hamiltonian function on classical phase space. If the Hamiltonian and $X$ are **not** in the prime ideal at some initial time, then $X$ **will never be**.

I have made some searching on the internet, but I have found only two papers that are rather abstract with no examples at all.

Comment: According to Theorem 5 of https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206136843, maximal ideals of codimension $\ge 1$ are prime. Also, maximal ideals of perfect Lie algebras are prime. That gives tons of examples, although maybe not in the case you're interested in.

Comment: This is one of the "two papers that are rather abstract with no examples at all" that I mentioned in the question. If there are "tons of examples", could you give me just one?

Comment: Take $A=$ your favourite simple Lie algebra (maybe $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, maybe $\mathfrak{sp}_{328}$), and $B=$ any Lie algebra you like. Then $0 \oplus B$ is a prime ideal in $A \oplus B$.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something @TorstenSchoeneberg, but representing an element of $A\oplus B$ as $(x,y)$, then $[(x_1,y_1),(x_1,y_2)]\in 0\oplus B$ ($x_1$ is not zero). Doesn't that mean that $0\oplus B$ is not a prime ideal?

Comment: The definition of prime ideal for Lie algebras needs ideals, not just elements (at least in one of the factors), see first page of that paper. Otherwise no ideal $I$ except the entire Lie algebra could ever be prime, since for $x \notin I$, $[x,x]=0\in I$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: A fancier example is $\pmatrix{0&0&*\\0&0&*\\0&0&0} \unlhd \pmatrix{a&b&*\\c&-a&*\\0&0&0}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg What is the case if we exclude that $[x,y]=0$ ? i.e

Does the definition of prime (or almost prime may be called) is :
An ideal $P$ of Lie algebra $L$ is prime if for any $x,y \ in L$  such that $[x,y] \neq 0 \in P $ then  $x \in P$ or $y \in P$?

Comment: I realise far too late that in my first comment, it should say "maximal ideals of codimension $>1$", not $\ge 1$.